# Script bash merge directories recursively and execute function for common files

Tags: bash

I need to bash script the merging of several directories recursively into one, however when copying an already existing file I want to execute a specific function.
I was thinking, as a start :

```
    mkdir merge
    cp -r dir1/* dir2/* merge/
```

but when a file already exists with the same name, I don't want to overwrite or discard, I want to execute my function, something like:

```
    if [-f $file]
    do myfunction() done
```

Any idea what my script should look like ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# make destination directory
dest=merge
mkdir -p $dest

# If file exists in target directory call `some_function`
# Do not overwrite existing files
for f in dir{1,2,3}/*; do
    [ -f "$dest/$(basename $f)" ] && some_function
    cp -rn "$f" "$dest"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple script like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

myfunction()
{
    printf "Omit %s\n" "$i"
}

dst=merge
mkdir -p "$dst"

# put a list of directories you want to copy here
for i in dir{1..10}
do
    if [ -e "$dst"/"$i" ]
    then
    myfunction "$i"
    continue
    fi

    cp -r "$i" "$dst"
done
```

It should work for simple cases but it could be optimized.  For
example, instead of calling `cp` multiple times one could create a
list of directories that should be copied and run `cp` only once or
using `xargs` to avoid `Argument list too long` issue.